# netlify Deployment issue: netlify.toml settings for SPA

Tags: netlify

**Disclaimer**: *I would ask this using either a.) some sort of support system on Netlify, b.) on a Netlify live chat session or c.) via their support community but a.) they don't let you, b.) they don't have one and c.) you can't currently create accounts or authorize from Netlify itself. (Seems like as an organisation, they don't really understand what would really nudge you into making you pay for a service).*

Anyways, I am having an issue with deploying an Vue.js SPA with VueRouter via a netlify.toml configuration. The issue is, all internal routing is not being handled by the SPA. My solution has always been to stick a `netlify.toml` config file in the root of the repository that I am deploying from, with the following:

```
# The following redirect is intended for use with most SPAs that handle routing internally.
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Yet, every internal route I visit gives me:

[image]

The **exact same** repo, but deployed on my personal plan 4 months ago (which has the same `netlify.toml` config in the same location) works fine. The application is also working on the current deployment branch locally. The routing is not broken. Has anyone else suffered with this inconsistent approach to redirects with Netlify?

Comment: I tried creating redirects using the netlify.toml and it worked for me, is there something you're doing differently with Vue Router? Here's an example repo for reference: https://github.com/shortdiv/checking-redirects

Comment: This behavior can also be observed if Netlify doesn't like something in toml file. Usually there'll be an error almost at the end of the deployment log that reads `Invalid TOML configuration format: ... (error)`. It causes the rest of the toml rules to be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, my specific fix was to do the following:

1. Add a _redirects file to the public directory of my Vue application, then:

```
# The following redirect is intended for use with most SPAs that handle routing internally.
/*    /index.html   200
```

Inside that file.

So for me, `netlify.toml` configuration for redirects is stil broken.

Comment: `public` directory is the key here. Don't repeat my mistake and put it into the root folder!

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Netlify guys please fix this weird behaviour, is clearly a bug!

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing exactly this behaviour as well. The `netlify.toml` contains:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

But doesn't work. The deployment summary even shows that netlify didn't pick up the redirect config at all:

```
No redirect rules processed

This deploy did not include any redirect rules. Learn more about redirects.
```

Comment: Hey, very odd - please check my answer, it helped me! :)

Comment: Yes, applied that same workaround to get it working. But the weird thing is that I have another site where the `netlify.toml` approach **does** work for specifying the SPA style redirect to index.html...

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos after digging around it turned out for us to be the result of writing `netlify.json` ourselves into the publish directory. We did that to dump metadata of the build context into the deployed site (build time / nr etc). This apparently conflicted with the config in `netlify.toml`. The fix for us was to use a different filename as output for that meta data.

Comment: I only have netlify.toml

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this issue like 2hrs ago from now, but the netlify.toml is working fine for me. Make sure you have set the public directory in your netlify setting to `'/'` (exactly where your netlifly.toml resides) instead of blank or anything else.